# curl can't list tenants servers

Tags: api, curl, openstack

I'm trying to list some info API style :) and what i have done till now is the following:
Using "curl" i can get the token out, with the token i can list the tenants, but after that i can't list the servers and other information. From the conductore if i execute the "nova --debug list --all-tenants" i get the results and get the commands that are executed with curl. So when im trying this from outside i get an error **"404" The resource could not be found.**

```
curl -i 'http://x.x.x.x:8774/v2/tenants/' -X GET -H "X-Auth-Token: <Token_ID>" -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: admin" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

And with the following command i don't get errors but i get some strange results:

```
curl -i 'http://x.x.x.x:8774/v2.0/<Tenant_ID>/servers' -X ET -H "X-Auth-Token: <Token_ID>" -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: <Tenant_ID>" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

and the output is:

```
HTTP/1.1 300 Multiple Choices
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 357 Date: Sun, 03 Apr
2016 21:59:48 GMT Connection: close

{"choices": [{"status": "CURRENT",
"media-types": [{"base":
 "application/xml", "type":
 "application/vnd.openstack.compute+xml;version=2"},
 {"base": "application/json", "type":
 "application/vnd.openstack.compute+json;version=2"}],
 "id": "v2.0", "links": [{"href":
 "http://x.x.x.x:8774/v2/v2.0/<Tenant_ID>/servers",
 "rel": "self"}]}]}
```

So my question is what is wrong here, i get output for tokens and listing tenants but i can't get output for listing servers ??

Thanks in advanced !

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find what is wrong with your curl - made requests to my host, but the answer is in the surface-response, obviously :)

You are trying to connect to nova service with version 2.0, but you have endpoint only with version=2 by default, so version must be 2.

Go to http://x.x.x.x/horizon/project/access_and_security/

and check the "API Access" tab, there are endpoints look to the compute one and use it to connect to service.
For example my compute service have endpoint:

```
Compute     http://controller:8774/v2/004e4c0366b74300b875adfd2c1bca4c
```

Take them to connect to services by curl.

Comment: Hi, in my compute service i have this endpoint:
 `Compute http://x.x.x.x:8774/v2/40e246807e04495f91e146a9ed04747f`
But again have the same error. Also from the Controler when i execute the `nova --debug list --all-tenants` i get the following output `curl -i 'http://x.x.x.x:8774/v2/40e246807e04495f91e146a9ed04747f/servers/detail?all_tenants=1' -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: admin" -H "X-Auth-Token
: {SHA1}blablabla"` and i have the output. But when im doing this from outside its not working for listing servers. But for tenants ok